# Discord.py : Forward message from one channel to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make some sort of say command with my bot that has "//" as prefix.

When typing `//say_next #some_channel` in the admin commands channel, I want that when I send a second message, it is copied and sent to the #some_channel

Here is my code

```
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def say_next(self, ctx: Context, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    if ctx.channel.id != get_from_config("admin_commands_channel_id"):
        return

    def message_check(m: discord.Message):
        return m.author == ctx.author

    try:
        message_to_send: discord.Message = await self.bot.wait_for("message", check=message_check, timeout=15)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send(content="Cancelled")
    else:
        await channel.send(content=message_to_send.content)
```

The problem is that this limits the forwarded message to only copy the original's message text.

What I want that forwarding to copy all the elements of the message, being an undefined number of embeds, a file or no file, etc ... but this cannot be done since the `Messageable.send` method cannot be used with a `Message` object, that is my `message_to_send` variable.

How can this forwarding be done, without having for each parameter of `Messageable.send` being an attribute of `message_to_send` so without something like this ?

```
content = message_to_send.content
embed = None if len(message_to_send.embeds) == 0 else message_to_send.embeds[0]
tts = message_to_send.tts
attachments = message_to_send.attachments
file = files = None
if len(attachments) > 1:
    files = attachments
else:
    file = attachments[0]
await channel.send(content=content, tts=tts, file=file, files=files, embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest approach would be the following:

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def say_next(self, ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    if ctx.channel.id != get_from_config("admin_commands_channel_id"):
        return

    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author

    try:
        msg = await self.bot.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=15.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("Cancelled")
    else:
        await channel.send(msg.content, tts=msg.tts, files=[await attch.to_file() for attch in msg.attachments])
```

I haven't included the embeds as normal users cannot send embeds.

There's not really much that I can say about this code, the only thing would be the `files` kwarg, it's simply a bit of list comprehension to convert the `discord.Attachment` instances to `discord.File` instances. You could think it won't work if you send only one file (or zero), I thought so too, but apparently it works.

Comment: The point of my question was how to send the message from another message object without having to kow how the message was constructed. I implemented something like this but if in the future a new type of data can be added in messages, the implementation would become obsolete unless I go back and fetch the new data type from the old message to pass it as parameter to the new messag.

Is there no way to send a message object via the send method in discord.py ?

Comment: No, you have to sadly do it "manually" and pass all the attributes by yourself.

Comment: You can add a [feature request](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/new?assignees=&labels=feature+request&template=feature_request.yml) in the github repo tho, it'd be a great addition to the library